# Comment traduire le « slow-moving trainwreck colliding with a dumpster fire » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, connotation, superlatifs

> We're watching a [slow-moving trainwreck](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trainwreck_in_slow_motion) collide with a [dumpster fire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumpster_fire).
> (Isaac Boltansky, BTIG, sur [CNN.com](https://www.cnn.com/2023/01/04/economy/house-speaker-economy-debt-ceiling/index.html))

Le contexte c'est que les marchés financiers américains semblent aimer une forme d'équilibre des pouvoirs qui se dessinait entre les partis représentés au sénat/chambre des représentants/présidence, une forme de [*gridlock*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gridlock) ou « embouteillage » des pouvoirs, au figuré. Mais vu la difficulté à faire élire un président de la chambre des représentants, l'analyste financier voit ça finalement de manière négative et s'est exprimé de la sorte pour le faire remarquer. En combinant deux expressions qui évoquent la perte de contrôle, l'incompétence, dont la première connotant le fait d'être conscient au moment où ça ce produit et la [deuxième](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumpster_fire) étant populaire et d'emploi récent ; l'une et l'autre s'additionnant pour atteindre possiblement un plus haut degré...

Comment pourrait-on traduire ça afin d'en obtenir la sémantique et, mieux encore, la phraséologie/morphologie, en enfilant par exemple deux locutions ?

Comment: Le *dumpster fire*, c'est les dangers imminents tels que le plafond de la dette ou la menace d'une récession, je me trompe ? Ou c'est l'inverse ?

Comment: @guillaume31 C'est une lecture possible mais je le voyais simplement comme une qualification de la situation d'indécision et de l'incapacité de choisir un président dans le contexte d'une frange rebelle du caucus républicain qu'on est incapable de gérer et qui est associée au chaos...

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que le sens général pourrait être communiqué comme

> Une catastrophe au ralenti descendante aux enfers

À l'autre côté, *slow-moving trainwreck* et *dumpster fire* ne sont pas des locutions bien enracinées dans la langue anglaise, mais plutôt d'imagerie americaine assez moderne. Ainsi on pourrait essayer d'utiliser l'imagerie moderne propre à la France, comme

> Le SNCF descendant aux enfers

J'avoue que je suis un peu préjugé contre le SNCF (comme j'utilise regulièrement la ligne Paris - Le Havre), mais ça a l'avantage de faire le lien avec des trains. Prenons donc une reference plus evidente (quoi que soit votre vue sur le problème), comme

> La reforme de retraite descendante aux enfers

Finalement, on pourrais egalement utiliser des references historiques:

> [La politique d'apaisement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politique_d%27apaisement) a la veille de la guerre

Dans ce contexte un français pourrait aussi utiliser la phrase anglaise: [*Peace for our time*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_for_our_time).

Comment: +1 pour l'expression imagée de la descente aux enfers, par contre y glisser la SNCF me parait un peu... exagéré

Comment: @guillaume31 Ca a été la première chose qui était venue à mon esprit, et elle me semble toujours la plus liée au sens littéral de la phrase en question. Neanmoins je reconnais que mon vue du SNCF n'est pas universelle, ce que j'admets dans ma reponse.

Comment: J'ai été surpris par ton choix de l'adjectif (descendant**e**) plutôt que du participe présent (invariable).

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî peut-être vous avez raison - j'avais senti que quelque chose ne collait pas dans cette phrase.

Answer (score 1):

*Slow-moving trainwreck* correspond à l'idée "d'annoncé", connu à l'avance : une catastrophe annoncée, un échec annoncé.

Pour garder l'idée d'incendie, on utilise souvent la métaphore "maison en feu" pour décrire une organisation en crise.

Sauf méprise sur le sens initial de l'image, cela pourrait donner :

> On assiste à la collision annoncée entre le train de l'économie qui déraille et une maison Congrès en feu.

Ou pour rester plus vague

> Un train en passe de dérailler va percuter une maison en feu sous nos yeux.

Pour garder l'aspect petit et légèrement moqueur de *dumpster fire* :

> C'est comme si une poubelle en feu se tenait sur le chemin d'un train déjà prêt à dérailler.